# ¿Cómo puedo pasar el id del usuario?

Tags: php, mysql-workbench

Tengo este select, el cual me tiene que arrojar  los resultados del usuario que se encuentre activo. Cuando el usuario inicie sesión, en automático le debe de mostrar los resultados(empresas) asignados, he visto que tengo que pasar el id del usuario de manera global, sin embargo el formulario del login hace la validación en el mismo formulario.

```
$query_empresa = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT emp.idt_empresas, emp.nombreE from usuario_empresa ue join t_usuarios us on ue.id_usuario = us.id_usuario join t_empresas emp on ue.id_empresa = emp.idt_empresas where us.id_usuario like '%%' order by emp.nombreE");
          $result_empresa = mysqli_num_rows($query_empresa);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para poder pasar valores de una parte del código de php a otra puedes usar las sesiones, tan solo tienes que hacer algo así `$_SESSION["userId"] = $idDeUsuario;` cuando tu usuario inicie sesión y entonces podrás usarlo en cualquier otra parte del código: `$id = $_SESSION["userId"];`

En la documentación de php puedes ver más información sobre el [uso de sesiones](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php)

Para poder usar las variables $_SESSION necesitarás iniciar una sesión primero, para ello se usa [session_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php).